# Possible to fire a callback in python on a shared memory update?

Tags: python, c, callback, shared-memory

This is on an rpi. I have a c process running that dumps data into shared memory and a python script that monitors this shared memory for updated data. C process sets shared memory flags and python scripts clear the shared memory flags. Python is currently just polling and I would like to get away from that if possible. The c process continuously runs outside of python and loads adc data into the shared memory buffer. Every N number of samples the c process sets a data ready flag. I wrote this process and so can change it if need be. I'm wondering if there is some way for the c process to fire a callback in python so that it doesnt have to poll. Am hoping to get some ideas from you all or possibly some nudges in the right direction. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Use a named pipe or FIFO. Per [the Linux `man fifo.7` page](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/fifo.7.html):

> A FIFO special file (a named pipe) is similar to a pipe, except
> that it is accessed as part of the filesystem.  It can be opened
> by multiple processes for reading or writing.  When processes are
> exchanging data via the FIFO, the kernel passes all data
> internally without writing it to the filesystem.  Thus, the FIFO
> special file has no contents on the filesystem; the filesystem
> entry merely serves as a reference point so that processes can
> access the pipe using a name in the filesystem.

A named pipes can be created with [the `mkfifo` command](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/mkfifo.1.html).

Open the pipe for reading in the Python process.  A read from the FIFO should block until another process writes to the pipe.

The C process can write a small chunk of data to the pipe when it needs to wake up the Python process.

Comment: Awesome! Thank you. A quick search on this topic also yielded a shared memory queue that may be helpful. Thank you!

Comment: @chrismec which shared memory queue did you find? Just curious, as I also have the same problem as the original piece.